# Early self-evaluation for islam.SE?

Tags: discussion

I have been reading other site's meta to see what is going on in other sites, and I see that generally one of the moderators request for self-evaluation after some time in beta. For example,

https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/evaluating-your-own-site-a-check-for-quality

https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1135/christianity-self-evaluation-lets-get-critical

https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/site-self-evaluation-how-are-you-doing

https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1006/jewish-life-and-learning-self-evaluation-how-are-you-doing

I asked about this on chat, but I was so excited about the idea, I couldn't help opening a thread about this.

As in above threads, I chose 10 random questions (by generating random numbers in range of total questions). To sum up the voting process;

> For each question, search the internet for the question as if you were
>   the asker! If our answer(s) is good (complete, well-written, answers
>   the question, useful, found in search results, etc) then **vote it up**!
>   If our answer(s) is bad (incomplete, poorly-written, off-topic,
>   incorrect, un-findable, worthless, etc) then **vote it down**! Comment with
>   anything you feel is worth noting, or to explain your voting choice.

**Note for the mods:** If you think it is inappropriate for non-mods to open these threads, please delete. No hard feelings :)

**Another note:** I had to add my comments on each one, because system didn't let me post an answer with only link. They are not authoritive or anything :)

Comment: +1 I think it's a little early, but we'll see :)

Comment: @Ansari A little early, yes. But it won't hurt I think :)

Comment: If you're having difficulty deciding whether to vote up or down, you can reference the handy-dandy decision making chart here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EQxi7.png

Comment: Just for your reference, these "Community Self Evaluations" are not posted by the moderators, *per se.* The questions are selected randomly by the system and then posted periodically by the Community Team at Stack Exchange. This is a somewhat new process still under development. Soon the whole process will be automated and become a regular part of community development. *Note: I have no objections to communities doing their own evaluations. Totally appropriate.*

Comment: In addition to what Robert said, we'll be posting an evaluation here in about a week's time, give or take. No harm in doing two of them, though, so I encourage everyone to look at the questions here and offer their opinions. :)

Comment: It looks like our answers are getting a bit too long to read. Maybe we should encourage people to write more concise answers, instead of quoting every single verse on the issue.

Answer (score 3):

[Why are there different translations of the Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1993/44)

> We have a good answer I think.

Answer (score 3):

[What is the definition of a kaffir?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/what-is-the-definition-of-kuffar)

> Yasar's comment: We have good answers.

Comment: after a very very small change to the title of the question, i got it to page three on google...... but i like the answers especially the second one ^_^

Answer (score 2):

[What is the Islamic stance on Internet Piracy?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-does-islam-stand-in-internet-piracy)

> Yasar's comment: I like the answers on this one.

Comment: first result on google!

Comment: Shows up good when searching specifically for "Internet piracy", but searching without that exact wording (e.g., "Software piracy" or "Intellectual property piracy"), our answer doesn't show, and would barely rate even if it did.

Answer (score 0):

[How was the order of the Qur'an decided?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/838/how-was-the-order-of-the-quran-decided)

> Yasar's comment: I think our answers are hard to read. Maybe they should have been shortened a little.

Comment: -1: three answers, first two are cut-and-paste and the third is low quality unreferenced.  This post is not making the internet a better place.

Answer (score 0):

[Where and when did the notion of "You must follow one madhhab exclusively" originate?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/652/where-and-when-did-the-notion-of-you-must-follow-one-madhhab-exclusively-origi)

> Yasar's comment: Answers are huge and hard to read IMO.

Answer (score 0):

[Is it more important to grow a beard, or to avoid resembling non-Muslims?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/507/is-it-more-important-to-grow-a-beard-or-to-avoid-resembling-non-muslims)

> Yasar's comment: One answer is huge, other one is low-quality. I would down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

[What does the Quran say about homosexuality?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/226/what-does-the-quran-say-about-homosexuality)

> Yasar's comment: I think we are good.

Answer (score -1):

[What is the source of the tafseer of the verse (3:37) that says rizq means scrolls of knowledge?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2076/44)

> We don't have an answer for this one. I think it didn't get enough attention. I think we have users capable of answering this one.

Answer (score -2):

[Is real estate business allowed in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/786/is-real-estate-business-allowed-in-islam)

> Yasar's comment: I am not sure about this one.

Comment: the answer didnt really answer the question i think the question had more to do with the mortgage and payment then with the transaction itself

Answer (score -2):

[What's the stand of Islam on a Muslim woman marrying a non-believer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/544/whats-the-stand-of-islam-on-a-muslim-woman-marrying-a-non-believer)

> Yasar's comment: I would -1 this one, as we don't have a quality answer for it.

Comment: i think its a duplicate